# "Crazy" Attempt to Understand Second-Order DEs on Manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, pseudo-differential-operators

(This is kind-of a crazy ramble; it's kind-of not a questions and kind-of not a request for comments, but it's more of a request for comments.)

We all know what the second derivative of a real-valued function of a real-variable, but I'm going to look at it in kind-of a crazy way. When we have $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}$ is kind-of a trivial Riemannian manifold, and the function's derivative is actually a 1-form, $df = f'(x)dx \in \Omega^1(\mathbb{R})$. Then, without actually realizing what we're doing, we take the Hodge star of $df$, $v(x) =\ ^*df = f'(x)$ and we take its differential $dv = f''(x)dx$, and then we take **its** Hodge star, $a(x) =\ ^*dv = f''(x)$.

To go from acceleration to position, we take the Hodge star of $a(x)$, $\omega = a(x)dx$, and, since $dx \wedge dx = 0$, $\omega$ is closed, and, supposing we're actually interested in a closed, bounded interval, or the whole real line, with no homology, we have that $\omega$ is exact, and hence has an anti-derivative $v(x)$. Then, we run the same gambit, take $v$'s Hodge star $\alpha$, note it is closed and hence exact, and take **its** anti-derivative, $f(x)$.

Now, suppose, for the sake of simplicity, space-time is a closed, pseudo-Riemannian (1,3) manifold $M^4$ (with no black holes or cusps or other icky phenomena). If we start with a real-valued function $f$ on $M$, we could take its differential $df$. We could then take the Hodge star $\theta =\ ^*df \in \Omega^3(M)$, take its differential $d\theta \in \Omega^4(M)$, and then take **its** Hodge star, $a(p)$. Multiplying this by some kind of mass and setting this equal to a scalar function $F(p)$ could give some version of Newton's Second Law.

Now, suppose we have a scalar function $a(p)$ on $M$. We could take its Hodge star, $\ ^*a \in \Omega^4(M)$; since $\Omega^5(M^4) = 0$, this is closed, and, supposing it is not a generator of $H^4(M)$, it would have an anti-derivative $\theta \in \Omega^3(M)$. Taking $\theta$'s Hodge star, we have $\alpha \in \Omega^1(M)$. If $d\alpha = 0 \in \Omega^2(M)$ and $\alpha$ is not a generator of $H^1(M)$, we could take an anti-derivative for $\alpha$, $f(p)$, a kind of "second integral" of $a(p)$.

We all know the d'Alembertian/Laplace-Beltrami operator, $\ ^*\Box^2 =\ ^*d^*d: \Omega^0(M) \to \Omega^0(M)$, has solutions to $\ ^*\Box^2f = 0$ with physical significance; it there any way this crazy way of looking at second-order DEs $m\ ^*\Box^2f = F$ could be useful?

Comment: (Really, what I'm trying to understand is why interpreting second-order ODEs on manifolds as sections of the double-tangent bundle that obey the canonical flip seems so "forced" or "alien" but interpreting them as some kind of $\ ^*d\ ^*d$ seems a natural extension of the 1D case.)

Comment: (Really, understanding second derivatives at all on manifolds is kind-of part of the problem: there're double-tangent bundles, Jacobian matrices, and $\ ^*d\ ^*d$s.)

Comment: This post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17325/why-is-cotangent-more-canonical-than-tangent appears to show the tangent bundle is natural for maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to M,and the cotangent bundle is more natural for map from M to the $\mathbb{R}$. Maybe all second derivatives can be interpreted as Jacobian matrices but "vary" with the domain and target? The 1D case is kind-of both simultaneously.

Comment: I guess a third thing is that one needs Christoffel symbols to even define the acceleration of a path on a Riemannian manifold, and so should need them to define second-order ODEs on r-manifolds, but Chrystoffel symbols are nowhere to be found with double-tangent bundles or *d*d's

Comment: It actually *is* a really vexing problem for me the difference between acceleration vectors as elements of the double-tangent bundle and covariant derivatives on Riemannian manifolds, and how second-order vector fields derived from Lagrangian functions (in a coordinate patch?) all fit together in the picture; hopefully, in a few days or weeks, I'll post an "answer" with the world-view I piece together